# Cast object to awaitable type unknown at compile time

Tags: c#, dynamic, async-await, casting, invoke

I have a concrete instance of `IHandler<T>` registered in the Microsoft `IServiceProvider`:

```cs
public interface IHandler<T>
{
    Task<T> HandleAsync();
}
```

The type `T` is only known at runtime, and I resolve the handler like this:

```cs
var myObject = new MyObject();
var handlerType = typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGenericType(myObject.GetType());
var handler = _serviceProvider.GetService(handlerType);
```

The problem is that the returned `handler` is of the type `object` (but when debugging I can verify that it in fact **is** the concrete type registered).

How can I convert the `object handler` into a variable that I can do `await handler.HandleAsync()` on?

---

**Edit:**

The question was originally a bit unclear as, ironically, I tried to make it simpler. The handlerType was like this before:

```cs
var handlerType = typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
```

indicating that `T` is a generic type, which it is not. The question has been updated to reflect that the `T` is an object instance.

Comment: So ```T``` is not a generic? If it is a generic type you should able to get it like this ```GetService<IHandler<T>>()```

Comment: Bit confused because you say you don´t have it but in your code example you get the type from ```T``` here ```typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));```

Comment: @Max Sorry for the confusion, `T` is not a generic, but an object instance. I made the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/interop/using-type-dynamic).

```
public interface IHandler<T> 
{
    Task<T> HandleAsync();
}

public class StringHandler : IHandler<string>
{
    public async Task<string> HandleAsync()
    {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static object GetHandler() => new StringHandler();

    public static void Main()
    {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        dynamic handler = GetHandler();                //<--- Here is the magic
        object result = await handler.HandleAsync();   //<---
        Console.WriteLine("Result is '{0}'", result);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Hello world!
```

[Link to fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yBqlEF)

Answer (score 2):

If you have `T` as your code example would indicate just call `GetService<IHandler<T>>` instead and it will give you the correct type back.

But in that case you would know the type at compile time. This would be preferable if at all possible.

---

Otherwise you´re gonna have to do some reflection at runtime. You can cast the return of the function to `Task` and `await` that. Calling `Result` on finished tasks will give you the result without executing it again.

```cs
var handlerType = typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
var handler = _serviceProvider.GetService(handlerType);

var handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod("HandleAsync");
var task = (Task)handleMethod.Invoke(handler, null);

await task;

var resultProperty = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result");
var result = resultProperty.GetValue(task);
```

Since you don´t know what you get back I´m not sure the return value will be of much use. If you just want to run the function you don´t need the last two lines.